# Is it possible to include other .whl files in my Python package?

Tags: python, pip, setuptools

I am making a python package that has some dependencies not hosted on PyPI or other indexes. I'd like to include those .whl dependencies in my repo/package, and install them from local files when the user pip installs my package.

I could add code to call pip directly on those files within my setup.py file, but I'm not sure of a reliable way to do that, especially considering if the user passed special arguments to pip originally.

Is there a proper way to do this? Or is it not something well supported by pip/setuptools?

Comment: I think the best solution—although pretty complicated, so it might not be worth it in every case—is to vendor the other packages, the way `requests` vendors `urllib3`, or `bs4` vendors `unicodedamnit`. You can include the wheels of the other modules in your source, or include the source (using anything from a `spam-1.2.3.tar.gz` source package to a git submodule), or even write code to fetch them as part of the build. However you do it, part of the build process for your `eggs` package is building the vendored package as `eggs.spam`, which you then collect into your wheel as part of `eggs`.

Comment: Alternatively: is there a reason you can't just host those other packages on your repo alongside your package, or even publish them to PyPI?