# How to include local whl files within a packaged tar.gz?

Tags: python, python-3.x, setuptools, setup.py, python-packaging

I have a python project called `hardware_tools` that I am trying to build into a distributable. The project structure is similar to:

```
hardware_tools/
├─ support/
│  ├─ __init__.py
│  ├─ arena_api-2.3.3-py3-none-any.whl
├─ __init__.py
├─ scripts.py
setup.py
```

The problem is that this project depends on a module that can not be installed from GitHub or PyPi. It is a locally saved wheel file downloaded from the manufacturers website. I can include the wheel file in the setup.py (below) and both `python setup.py install` and `python setup.py sdist` run without error. The problem is that when I try to install the output *.tar.gz file in a different environment (using the same base interpreter) I get an error reading:

`ERROR: <WHEEL PATH>\arena_api-2.3.3-py3-none-any.whl is not a valid wheel filename.`

I have tried changing the name of the wheel to be "arena_api-2.3.3.whl" and "arena_api-2.3.3-cp310-cp310-win_amd64.whl" according to [PEP 427](https://peps.python.org/pep-0427/#:%7E:text=File%20Format-,File%20name%20convention,whl%20.&text=Distribution%20name%2C%20e.g.%20%27django%27%2C%20%27pyramid%27.&text=Distribution%20version%2C%20e.g.%201.0.), but with no luck. I also used another *.whl file and I got the same error. Then I tried removing the *.whl from the build and installing hardware_tools.tar.gz, which does work, but obviously defeats my purpose.

Please let me know if anyone has had a similar problem or if there is simply something blatantly wrong with my setup file. Thank you in advance!

```
import io, os, sys
from shutil import rmtree
from setuptools import (find_packages, setup, Command)

# Metadata
NAME = 'hardware_tools'
DESCRIPTION = 'Module to maintain control of hardware tools including cameras, stages, etc.'
URL = ''
EMAIL = ''
AUTHOR = ''
REQUIRES_PYTHON = '>=3.8.*'
VERSION = '2.0.1'

# Create paths
here = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
here_support = os.path.join(here, "hardware_tools\\support")
wheel_path = os.path.join(here_support, "arena_api-2.3.3-py3-none-any.whl")

# Required or optional package dependencies
REQUIRED = [
    "Pillow", "PIPython", "RsInstrument", "aardvark-py", "keyboard", "labjack-ljm", "mecademicpy", "numpy==1.24.4",
    "pylablib", "pymba", "pyueye", "screeninfo", "seabreeze", "thorlabs-apt", "opencv-contrib-python", "matplotlib",
    "arena_api @ file://localhost/%s" % wheel_path
]

try:
    with io.open(os.path.join(here, 'README.txt'), encoding='utf-8') as f:
        long_description = '\n' + f.read()
except FileNotFoundError:
    long_description = DESCRIPTION

# Load __version__.py as a dictionary.
about = {}
if not VERSION:
    project_slug = NAME.lower().replace("-", "_").replace(" ", "_")
    with open(os.path.join(here, project_slug, '__version__.py')) as f:
        exec(f.read(), about)
else:
    about['__version__'] = VERSION

# Setup project
setup(
    name=NAME,
    version=about['__version__'],
    description=DESCRIPTION,
    long_description=long_description,
    long_description_content_type="text/markdown",
    author=AUTHOR,
    author_email=EMAIL,
    python_requires=REQUIRES_PYTHON,
    url=URL,
    packages=find_packages(exclude=["tests", "*.tests", "*.tests.*", "tests.*"]),
    dependency_links=[wheel_path],
    data_files=[("support", ["hardware_tools\\support\\config.json", "hardware_tools\\support\\aardvark.dll",
                             wheel_path.split(here)[1][1:]])],
    install_requires=REQUIRED,
    include_package_data=True,
    license="MIT",
    classifiers=[
        # Full list: https://pypi.python.org/pypi?%3Aaction=list_classifiers
        "License :: OSI Approved :: MIT License",
        "Programming Language :: Python",
        "Programming Language :: Python :: 3",
        "Programming Language :: Python :: 3.8",
        "Programming Language :: Python :: 3.9",
        "Programming Language :: Python :: 3.10",
        "Programming Language :: Python :: Implementation :: CPython",
        "Programming Language :: Python :: Implementation :: PyPy"
    ],
    cmdclass={
        "upload": UploadCommand,
    },
)
```

Note: I have seen the question posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51446954/is-it-possible-to-include-other-whl-files-in-my-python-package), but I don't believe the "solutions" would work for my case. I can not use `requests` because you need to have an account with the company to download the package, and I don't want to post their package to PyPi if they haven't already (legal issues with IP?).

Comment: If you don't have permissions to redistribute the hardware vendor's code, it doesn't matter whether you are redistributing it via PyPI or by bundling it up in your package, you are still probably doing something you shouldn't (bearing in mind, IANAL). The best option, IMO, is to point users of your code to wherever the vendor keeps it. On the other hand, if you think that the license does allow redistribution, you should be free to put it on PyPI, put it on GitHub, host the wheel in a cloud storage blob, etc.

Comment: Ah ok that's unfortunate... but thank you for your answer!